# 'startAt' and 'endAt' is not filtering the data using angularfire2 4.0.0

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

This is the structure in my firebase:

```
"receipts" : {
"-L7ug4xPoZYvk72Pynjh" : {
  "date" : "18-2-2018",
  "name" : "ABC",
  "price" : 50,
  "product" : "1122",
  "quantity" : 1
},
"-L7ug5phx4x7OUA8Pyxa" : {
  "date" : "18-3-2018",
  "name" : "XYZ",
  "price" : 50,
  "product" : "1122",
  "quantity" : 1
}
```

I'm using angularfire 2 version 4.0.0. I want to limit the results using `startAt` and `endAt` with the combination of `orderByChild` on `"date"`. I'm using the following code but it returns all the data present in the database:

```
getFullReceipts(dateFrom, dateTo) {
 console.log(dateFrom); //dateFrom = 3-3-2018
 console.log(dateTo);   //dateTo = 31-3-2018
 return this.afData.list('receipts', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'date',
    startAt: dateFrom,
    endAt: dateTo
  }
});
```

}

This code should only return one record with the date `18-3-2018` but returns all the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string format in which you store the dates is not easily sortable. Since Firebase does a string comparison on these strings, they don't match your intended result. This is easiest to see if we reproduce the problem in plain JavaScript, without Firebase being involved:

```js
var dates = [
  "18-2-2018",
  "18-3-2018"
];

var dateFrom = "3-3-2018"
  , dateTo = "31-3-2018"
  ;
  
dates.forEach(function(date) {
  if (date < dateFrom) console.log(date+" is before "+dateFrom);
  if (date > dateFrom) console.log(date+" is after "+dateFrom);
  if (date < dateTo) console.log(date+" is before "+dateTo);
  if (date > dateTo) console.log(date+" is after "+dateTo);
  if (date >= dateFrom && date <= dateTo) console.log(date+" is within range");
});
```

Consider storing them in an [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), e.g. `2018-03-03` and `2018-03-31`. Or store them as timestamps, which are numeric (milliseconds since the epoch) and this don't have this problem.

```js
var dates = [
  "2018-02-18",
  "2018-03-18"
];

var dateFrom = "2018-03-03"
  , dateTo = "2018-03-31"
  ;

dates.forEach(function(date) {
  if (date < dateFrom) console.log(date+" is before "+dateFrom);
  if (date > dateFrom) console.log(date+" is after "+dateFrom);
  if (date < dateTo) console.log(date+" is before "+dateTo);
  if (date > dateTo) console.log(date+" is after "+dateTo);
  if (date >= dateFrom && date <= dateTo) console.log(date+" is within range");
});
```

Comment: i tried using the `2018-3-18` format. It does the trick but the only problem now if when I select date such a `2018-3-3` it doesn't return anything but if I select `2018-3-1`, a firebase returns the result. @Frank

Comment: For your first comment: note that in my sample the dates are padded with a leading `0` to always be the same length, otherwise it won't work. But timestamps are a great solution too.